# WakeLock for SMS receiving and replying with an IntentService

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which when a sms arrives query the database and reply to the sender.

I start an IntentService in sms broadcast receiver because the process may take some times and be killed by the system.

I wonder if it's necessary to acquire a wakelock in broadcast receiver before starting the service or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BR will make it's job. But as soon as you call "startService()" this job is done and service not started yer (just intent has been but to system. So - yes, it's good practice to ensure that WL is aquired since broadcast received to job done.
You can extend Application class, to have simple access to your WL from different components of application (BR, Service etc.)